# Gradle weird errors on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration

I'm trying to deploy our projects on Jenkins, but each component is just using the settings.gradle file in the root directory, even if I have added a separate settings.gradle file for each of them.

Currently, I have a structure like this.

- ROOT

  - UI

    - ship (include settings.gradle & build.gradle in this folder)
    - order
    - quality

      - review
  - settings.gradle
  - build.gradle

I have `include("ui:shipnotice")` in the settings.gradle file for both the root and the ship directory.

I have a task called copy, when I tried to invoke this task under the ship folder, I need to use ../../graldew --no-daemon --info copy

I got the following `Settings evaluated using settings file 'xxx/ui/shipnotice/settings.gradle.kts'.`

However, things become weird after I deploy it using Jenkins. In Jenkins, it keeps using the settings.gradle file in the root directory.

```
Settings evaluated using settings file '/home/jenkins/workspace/xxx/settings.gradle.kts'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Project directory '/home/jenkins/workspace/xxx/ui/shipnotice' is not part of the build defined by settings file '/home/jenkins/workspace/xxx/settings.gradle.kts'. If this is an unrelated build, it must have its own settings file.
```

I tried to add `rootProject.name = "shipnotice"    include("ui:shipnotice")` to make shipnotice as the root project, but it still using the file from root.

Anyone could give me some idea about this error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting rid of the nested `settings.gradle`. This is [not a recommended setup](https://docs.gradle.org/6.6.1/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:settings_file).

What's most likely happening in your Jenkins build is that the folder from which the Gradle command is executed is the root folder of the checkout. And so the `settings.gradle` from that root is picked up.

Comment: Thanks, Louis. I found out that in my Jenkinsfile, I forgot using {env.workspace} in one place. After I changed it, it has been solved. However, I'm curious about deleting those redundant settings files. 
I understand that Gradle could find the sub-projects in the same directory. However, for the case of the review component, which is in a deeper directory. How could it be found without the settings.gradle file?